# split dmp file into multiple dmp files?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g EE in Windows XP Operating System. I have a dmp file of 5 GB in my hard disc. I want to split this large dmp file into multiple dmp files and after splitting I will import those multiple dmp files.

I saw the following links but found not helpful.

1. [Split a dmp](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about648085.html)
2. [Split a dmp before import](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.databases.oracle.misc/2009-11/msg00022.html)

How can I split this large dmp file?

Comment: Have you tried exporting different sets of tables in different dmp files?

Comment: no i have not done it, while exporting, all tables are getting into one dmp file

Comment: OK. Instead of exporting the entire user, you can export tables in groups. I believe the table names can also be parametrized. So you will end up with multiple dmp files for the same user, but containing different tables.

Comment: yes this can be done by parametrized but i have a dmp file already , i have not exported it, just i want to split it into multiple dmp files

Comment: why do you need multiple dump files?

Comment: i have been given this task to do, i am not able to find any solution till now, after split i have to import it by a different user and password into oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a dump & importing it using a different user doesn't require multiple dump files, just pass the from/to user parameters

```
imp scott/tiger file=emp.dmp fromuser=scott touser=jeff tables=dept
```

If you still want to split to multiple files, you can try

```
exp scott/tiger FILE=D:F1.dmp,E:F2.dmp FILESIZE=10m LOG=multi-split.log
```

This'll create a new dump file every 10Mb.

As far as splitting an existing dump file, yeah I don't think that's possible. On what basis do you want to split them? Dump files are binary files, so text parsing them doesn't work.

Not really sure if that's what you want. You need to post your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

why you dont set condition for export command like this:

```
exp scott/tiger file=A1.dump log=A.log table=table1 query=\"ri>0 and ri< 1000000\"
exp scott/tiger file=A2.dump log=A2.log table=table1 query=\"ri>=1000000 and ri< 2000000\"
```